# How to find approximate matching strings in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a list of university names, which is scrambled due to the original data.

```
x <- c(NA, "UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", NA, "MANIPAL UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF HUDDERSFIELD", NA, "SDM COLLEGE OF MEDICAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", 
"INTERNATIONAL MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", "PANINEEYA MAHAVIDYALAYA INSTITUTE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND RESEARCH CENTER", 
"SHANDONG UNIVERSITY", NA, "ACT HEALTH", NA, "ICT – INSTITUTE OF SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY – SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY – UNESP", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", "BASKENT UNIVERSITY", 
NA, "ARISTOTLE UNIVERSITY OF THESSALONIKI", "CHIANG MAI UNIVERSITY", 
"GUANGDONG PROVINCE", "PACIFIC DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", 
"DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL EPIDEMIOLOGY", "FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF PARAÍBA", 
"SAINT LOUIS UNIVERSITY", "FACULTY OF DENTISTRY", NA, "GOMAL MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
NA, "PEKING UNIVERSITY SCHOOL AND HOSPITAL OF STOMATOLOGY", "BOSTON UNIVERSITY", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF ADELAIDE", "UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", "NOTREPORTED", 
"KATHMANDU UNIVERSITY", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF CAMPINAS", "INSTITUTE OF LEGAL MEDICINE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF BOLOGNA", "COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES", "UNIVERSITY OF MALTA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LAUSANNE", "LEUVEN BIOSTATISTICS AND STATISTICAL BIOINFORMATICS CENTRE (L-BIOSTAT)", 
"BEATRIX CHILDREN HOSPITAL/UMCG", NA, "UNIVERSIDAD DE TARAPACÁ", 
"SHANGHAI JIAO TONG UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", "UNIVERSITY OF BELGRADE SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", 
"GAZIOSMANPASA UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITÄTSKLINIKUM MÜNSTER", 
"QUISISANA HOSPITAL", NA, "CENTRO MÉDICO DOCENTE LA TRINIDAD", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", "CHIANG MAI UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF FIRENZE", "DATE OF BIRTH FOUNDATION", "UC DAVIS KAREN C. DRAYER WILDLIFE HEALTH CENTER-ORCAS ISLAND OFFICE", 
"CAMPUS UAB", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", 
"FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF PARANÁ", "THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ICELAND", "PERNAMBUCO UNIVERSITY", "KING'S COLLEGE LONDON DENTAL INSTITUTE", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", "XI’AN JIAOTONG UNIVERSITY HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SALENTO", "UNIVERSITY OF FIRENZE", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL DÜSSELDORF", 
"BHARATI VIDYAPEETH DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", 
NA, "ADVANCED INSTITUTE OF HEALTH SCIENCES-NORTH (ISCS-N)", "HACETTEPE UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF BARI", "FACULTÉ DE MÉDECINE SECTEUR NORD", "FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF PERNAMBUCO", 
"UNIVERSITY OF AKDENIZ", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", 
"GHENT UNIVERSITY", "PEKING UNIVERSITY SCHOOL AND HOSPITAL OF STOMATOLOGY", 
"AUSTRIA", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "UNIVERSITY OF BRADFORD", 
"CRANFIELD UNIVERSITY", "QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", 
"INSTITUTE OF CHILD HEALTH", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL LEIPZIG", 
"UNIVERSIDADE DO PORTO", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF SPLIT", "PEOPLE'S COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND RESEARCH CENTRE", 
NA, "HAMEDAN UNIVERSITY OF MEDICAL SCIENCES", "GHENT UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "FACULDADE DE MEDICINA DA UNIVERSIDADE DO PORTO", 
"UNIVERSITY OF TORONTO MISSISSAUGA", "UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO (FOUSP)", 
"KING'S COLLEGE LONDON DENTAL INSTITUTE", "POLYTECHNIC UNIVERSITY OF MARCHE", 
"INSTITUTE FOR CT AND MRT DIAGNOSTICS", "UNIVERSITY OF FLORIDA", 
"GRIFFITH UNIVERSITY", "INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE MEDICINA LEGAL E CIÊNCIAS FORENSES", 
"BASKENT UNIVERSITY", "PUBLIC HEALTH CENTRE", "CHIBA UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF CONCEPCIÓN", "UCL EASTMAN DENTAL HOSPITAL", "XI’AN JIAOTONG UNIVERSITY HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER", 
"KUWAIT UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSIDADE DE SÃO PAULO", "UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL DO PARANÁ - UFPR", 
NA, NA, "UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", "KU LEUVEN - UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY CLINICS OF DENTAL MEDICINE", "JUSTUS-LIEBIG-UNIVERSITY GIESSEN", 
"UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS LEUVEN", "XI’AN JIAOTONG UNIVERSITY HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER", 
NA, "SARDAR PATEL POST GRADUATE INSTITUTE OF DENTAL AND MEDICAL SCIENCES", 
"GITAM DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", 
"SORBONNE PARIS CITÉ", "MAULANA AZAD INSTITUTE OF DENTAL SCIENCES", 
"LEUVEN BIOSTATISTICS AND STATISTICAL BIOINFORMATICS CENTRE (L-BIOSTAT)", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS OF LEICESTER", 
"INSTITUTE OF LEGAL MEDICINE", "AIX-MARSEILLE UNIVERSITÉ", "INSTITUTO POLITÉCNICO DE VISEU", 
"SMITHSONIAN INSTITUTION", "HARVARD UNIVERSITY", "DEPARTAMENTO DE ODONTOLOGIA SOCIAL DA FACULDADE DE ODONTOLOGIA DA UNIVERSIDADE DE SAO PAULO (FOUSP)", 
"AFFILIATED WITH SHANGHAI JIAO TONG UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", 
"EDINBURGH UNIVERSITY MEDICAL SCHOOL", "UNIVERSITY OF COLORADO AT BOULDER", 
NA, NA, "KING FAISAL HOSPITAL AND RESEARCH CENTRE", "QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", 
"SIFA UNIVERSITY", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", 
"GOA DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", "S NIJALINGAPPA MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"JUSTUS-LIEBIG-UNIVERSITY GIESSEN", "SEOUL NATIONAL UNIVERSITY", 
"FULING CENTER HOSPITAL OF CHONGQING CITY", "WENZHOU MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", 
"NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", "KING'S COLLEGE LONDON DENTAL INSTITUTE", 
"KING'S COLLEGE LONDON DENTAL INSTITUTE", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL DÜSSELDORF", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LEICESTER", "XI'AN JIAOTONG UNIVERSITY HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER", 
"UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSIDADE SAGRADO CORAÇÃO-USC-BAURU", 
"UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ISTANBUL", "UNIVERSITY OF ANKARA", "XI'AN JIAOTONG UNIVERSITY", 
NA, "AKDENIZ UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", 
"S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITY OF ADELAIDE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF HILDESHEIM", "UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "UNIVERSITY OF PRETORIA", "THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "HOSPITAL SANT JOAN DE DÉU", "SDM COLLEGE OF MEDICAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", 
"SAARLAND UNIVERSITY", "FRANCE", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", 
"UNIVERSITÉ DE TOULOUSE III", "THE SAINTS CYRIL AND METHODIUS UNIVERSITY OF SKOPJE", 
"PUNAN HOSPITAL OF PUDONG NEW DISTRICT", "CHIANG MAI UNIVERSITY", 
"RIYADH COLLEGES OF DENTISTRY AND PHARMACY", "SPECIALIST CLINIC FOR ORTHODONTICS", 
"PAUL SABATIER UNIVERSITY", "ERCIYES UNIVERSITY", "CHARLES UNIVERSITY IN PRAGUE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", "CHIBA UNIVERSITY", "UNESP - UNIV ESTADUAL PAULISTA - SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", 
"HEBREW UNIVERSITY-HADASSAH", "UNIVERSITY OF BARI", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", "UNIVERSITY OF BELGRADE - SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", 
"FRANCE", "UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO", "CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", "UNIVERSITY OF BARI", "UNIVERSITY OF HONG KONG", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "UNIVERSIDADE DE SÃO PAULO", "RVS DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"SATHYABAMA UNIVERSITY", "ISTANBUL UNIVERSITY", "RAGAS DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF RIJEKA", "FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF PARAÍBA", "A.E.C.S. MAARUTI COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES", 
"S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", "SMITHSONIAN INSTITUTION", 
"KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "UNIVERSITY OF NORTH CAROLINA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WYOMING", "YENEPOYA UNIVERSITY", "YENEPOYA UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SARAJEVO", "FAMILY DENTAL CLINIC", "INONU UNIVERSITY", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF TRIESTE", "UNIVERSITY OF TRIESTE", "S N MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LEICESTER", "UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", "THE OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY", 
"LINCOLN", "UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", "UNIVERSITY OF HONG KONG", 
"UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", "CHIBA UNIVERSITY", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ISTANBUL", "CHARITE-UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"WORLD HEALTH ORG. COLLABORATING CENTRE FOR RESEARCH AND MANAGEMENT IN ZOONOSES CONTROL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", "MASHHAD UNIVERSITY OF MEDICAL SCIENCES", 
"UNIVERSITY OF NEWCASTLE", "UNIVERSITY OF BARI", "TERNA DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", 
"QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "KARADENIZ TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "KATERINSKAACUTE", "SIMON FRASER UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA", "UNIVERSITY OF TRIESTE", 
"CHARITÉ-UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", "GOVERNMENT MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF THE WEST INDIES", "UNIVERSITY OF KWAZULU-NATAL", 
"SICHUAN UNIVERSITY", "IWATE MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", "HACETTEPE UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO (USP)", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", 
"ABANT IZZET BAYSAL UNIVERSITY", "MONASH UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF OTAGO", 
"FROME ROAD", "HAINAN", "PDM DENTAL COLLEGE AND RESEARCH INSTITUTE", 
"APPALACHIAN STATE UNIVERSITY", "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF KENT", 
"SÜLEYMAN DEMIREL UNIVERSITY", "THE UNIVERSITY OF HONG KONG", 
"KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "MONASH UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", 
"S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", "ATATURK UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF NEWCASTLE", "DIPARTIMENTO DI MEDICINA CLINICA E BIOTECNOLOGIE APPLICATE", 
"DENTAL COLLEGE DAMASCUS UNIVERSITY", "AGA KHAN UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL", 
"NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "UNIVERSITY OF FIRENZE", 
"UNIVERSITY HOSPITALS LEUVEN", "MISSISSIPPI STATE UNIVERSITY", 
"KALKA DENTAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITY OF ROME TOR VERGATA", "GRIFFITH UNIVERSITYQLD", 
"PORTO UNIVERSITY", "QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "STOCKHOLM UNIVERSITY", 
"MASHHAD UNIVERSITY OF MEDICAL SCIENCES", "JORDAN UNIVERSITY OF SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", "UTTAR PRADESH DENTAL COLLEGE", "JIKEI UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF TRIESTE", "THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", "STATE UNIVERSITY OF CAMPINAS", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "SRI HASANAMBA DENTAL COLLAGE AND HOSPITAL", 
"HELSINKI UNIVERSITY CENTRAL HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", 
"DIVISION OF CRANIOFACIAL SCIENCES", "MEDICAL UNIVERSITY OF LUBLIN", 
"KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "THE CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY OF KOREA", 
"DASWANI DENTAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI BARI", 
"UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "MONASH UNIVERSITY", "MICHIGAN STATE UNIVERSITY", 
"GUY'S HOSPITAL", "AUSTRIA", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", "RAFSANJAN UNIVERSITY OF MEDICAL SCIENCE", 
"GAUHATI MEDICAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", "GEORG-AUGUST-UNIVERSITAET GOETTINGEN", 
"ATATURK UNIVERSITY", "JAWAHARLAL NEHRU MEDICAL COLLEGE", "KAROLINSKA INSTITUTET", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", "PEKING UNIVERSITY SCHOOL AND HOSPITAL OF STOMATOLOGY", 
"NOTREPORTED", "WASHINGTON", "PEOPLE'S COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES", 
"INDIANA UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "M.M. UNIVERSITY", 
"BOULEVARD PIERRE DRAMARD", "SPD COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITÉ PAUL SABATIER", 
"KARADENIZ TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", NA, 
"ONDOKUZ MAYS UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSIDADE DE SÃO PAULO", "DENTAL MEDICINE FACULTY OF PORTO UNIVERSITY", 
"S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", 
"UNIVERSIDADE DE LISBOA", "SANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA UNIVERSITY", 
"MONASH UNIVERSITY", "MUSEU DE ZOOLOGIA DA UNIVERSIDADE DE SÃO PAULO", 
"MINIA UNIVERSITY", "MEDICAL UNIVERSITY OF LUBLIN", "UNIVERSITY OF KENT", 
"NC STATE UNIVERSITY", NA, "THE CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY OF KOREA", 
"SAVEETHA UNIVERSITY", "THE UNIVERSITY OF QUEENSLAND", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"ATATURK UNIVERSITY", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "WUHAN UNIVERSITY", 
"FRANCE", "S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", "HARVARD UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER", "ARLINGTON", "SICHUAN UNIVERSITY", 
"AICHI-GAKUIN UNIVERSITY", "QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", 
"YONSEI UNIVERSITY COLLEGE OF DENTISTRY", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"HEALTH CENTRE CERBERUS", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", "QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", 
"TOKYO DENTAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITY OF PERNAMBUCO", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI FIRENZE", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER AT SAN ANTONIO", 
"KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"J.S.S. MEDICAL COLLEGE", "KUWAIT UNIVERSITY", "CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY LEUVEN", 
"NIHON UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "NATIONAL CENTER OF MEDICINE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF YORK", "JCD DENTAL COLLEGE", "S.D.M. COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND HOSPITAL", 
"UNIVERSIDAD AUTÓNOMA DE MADRID", "EX-LECTURE PDM DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"CHARITÉ - UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", "MEDICAL NOBEL INSTITUTE", 
"BOULEVARD PIERRE DRAMARD", "PEOPLE'S COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES AND RESEARCH CENTRE", 
"AKITA UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF CONCEPCIÓN", "AGA KHAN UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL", 
"METRO SOUTH HEALTH SERVICE DISTRICT", "UNIVERSITY OF SANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA", 
"SUN YET-SEN UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "THE UNIVERSITY OF SHEFFIELD", 
"UNIVERSITY OF PITTSBURGH", "THE AGA KHAN UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO DENTAL SCHOOL", "UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL CHARITÉ BERLIN", 
"NOTREPORTED", "CHARITÉ - UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", "CHARITÉ-UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"SCHOOL OF DENTAL MEDICINE UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", "FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF RIO GRANDE DO NORTE (URFN)", 
"NATIONAL INSTITUTE OF DENTAL AND CRANIOFACIAL RESEARCH", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSIDADE DE SÃO PAULO", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF RIJEKA", "THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", 
"KUWAIT UNIVERSITY", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF COIMBRA", "UNIVERSITY OF SARAJEVO", 
"UNIVERSITÄT ZÜRICH", "SDM COLLEGE OF DENTAL SCIENCES", NA, 
"UNIVERSIDAD COMPLUTENSE DE MADRID", "ARIZONA STATE UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WINNIPEG", "UNIVERSITY OF LIVERPOOL", "KING'S COLLEGE LONDON DENTAL INSTITUTE", 
"WESTMEAD CENTRE FOR ORAL HEALTH", "KING'S COLLEGE DENTAL HOSPITAL", 
"HEBREW UNIVERSITY-HADASSAH SCHOOL OF DENTAL MEDICINE", "HEBREW UNIVERSITY-HADASSAH", 
"DIPARTIMENTO DI MEDICINA CLINICA E BIOTECNOLOGIE APPLICATE", 
"SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "UNIVERSIDADE DE COIMBRA", "GOETHE-UNIVERSITY OF FRANKFURT MAIN", 
"PDM DENTAL COLLEGE", NA, "SCHOOL OF ORTHODONTICS", "INSTITUTE OF FORENSIC SCIENCE", 
"AKITA UNIVERSITY FACULTY OF MEDICINE", "TOULOUSE", "NATIONAL INSTITUTE OF DENTAL AND CRANIOFACIAL RESEARCH", 
"TOKYO DENTAL COLLEGE", "MICHIGAN STATE UNIVERSITY", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"HELSINKI UNIVERSITY CENTRAL HOSPITAL", "BASQUE INSTITUTE OF LEGAL MEDICINE", 
"FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO", "PRIVATE DENTAL OFFICE", 
"UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "ERCIYES UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF THE WESTERN CAPE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF PERADENIYA", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF THE WESTERN CAPE", "UNIVERSITY OF THE WESTERN CAPE", 
"ORTHODONTICS PT. BHAGWAT DAYAL SHARMA POST GRADUATE INSTITUTE OF MEDICAL SCIENCES", 
"ARLINGTON", "P.D.M. DENTAL COLLEGE", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", 
"KANSAS STATE UNIVERSITY", "DEPARTMENT OF DEVELOPMENTAL AND SURGICAL SCIENCE", 
"UNIVERSITÄTSKLINIKUM MÜNSTER", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "SUBHARTI DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ADELAIDE", "CHARITÉ - UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"BATIMENT VILLEMIN", "UNIVERSITI SAINS MALAYSIA", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", 
"INSTITUT FÜR RECHTSMEDIZIN DES UNIVERSITÄTSKLINIKUMS DÜSSELDORF", 
"HUAZHONG UNIVERSITY OF SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY", "UNIVERSITY OF TOKYO", 
"BERNHARD GOTTLIEB UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", 
"INSTITUTE OF INVESTIGATION", "UNIVERSITY OF YORK", "UNIVERSITY OF BARI", 
"SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "NOTREPORTED", "PARIS DESCARTES UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SOUTH FLORIDA", "JOINT POW/MIA ACCOUNTING COMMAND-CENTRAL IDENTIFICATION LABORATORY (JPAC-CIL)", 
"WASHINGTON", "JOINT POW/MIA ACCOUNTING COMMAND - CENTRAL IDENTIFICATION LABORATORY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF TENNESSEE", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "ROSKILDE UNIVERSITY", 
"NOTREPORTED", "PAEDIATRIC DENTISTRY AND ORTHODONTICS. FACULTY OF ODONTOLOGY. MADRID COMPLUTENSE UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF OTAGO", "KING SAUD UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", 
"ARIZONA STATE UNIVERSITY", "OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY", "MEDIZINISCHE UNIVERSITÄT", 
"UNIVERSITY OF YORK", "UNIVERSITY OF ONDOKUZ MAYIS", "KING'S COLLEGE LONDON DENTAL INSTITUTE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "POLAND", "CHARITÉ - UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "PDM DENTAL COLLEGE AND RESEARCH INSTITUTE", 
"UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI MILANO", NA, "NOTREPORTED", "DENTAL SCHOOL AND HOSPITAL", 
"ERCIYES UNIVERSITY", "COIMBRA", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", NA, 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "CHARITÉ - UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "KASTURBA MEDICAL COLLEGE", "NA", "UNIVERSITY OF VIENNA", 
"OSAKA UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF FLORENCE", "TRIPLER ARMY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"SEOUL NATIONAL UNIVERSITY", NA, "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", 
"MAX PLANCK INSTITUTE FOR EVOLUTIONARY ANTHROPOLOGY", "OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF VIENNA", "UNIVERSITY OF TENNESSEE HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER", 
NA, "ATATÜRK UNIVERSITY", "ST STEPHENS HOSPITAL", "CHARITÉ-UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ANKARA", "WROCŁAW MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", "SÃO PAULO STATE UNIVERSITY", 
"INSTITUTE OF FORENSIC MEDICINE", "UNIVERSITY OF FORTALEZA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SOUTHERN DENMARK", NA, "JOHANNES GUTENBERG UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "HEALTH CENTER ŠIBENIK", "ARIZONA SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY AND ORAL HEALTH", 
"MICHIGAN STATE UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", "RADBOUD UNIVERSITY NIJMEGEN MEDICAL CENTER", 
"RADBOUD UNIVERSITY NIJMEGEN MEDICAL CENTER", "JORDAN UNIVERSITY OF SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY", 
"TEXAS A AND M UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", "UNIVERSITY OF THE WESTERN CAPE", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "BARTS AND THE LONDON SCHOOL OF MEDICINE AND DENTISTRY", 
"CHARITÉ-UNIVERSITÄTSMEDIZIN BERLIN", "LEIDEN UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"BART'S AND THE LONDON SCHOOL OF MEDICINE AND DENTISTRY", "SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF BRITISH COLUMBIA", "PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDADE CATÓLICA DO PARANÁ", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WATERLOO", "UNIVERSITY OF AUVERGNE", "UNIVERSITY OF LJUBLJANA", 
"BARTS AND THE LONDON SCHOOL OF MEDICINE AND DENTISTRY", "INSTITUTE OF CHEMICAL TECHNOLOGY", 
"SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF NORTH TEXAS", 
"NOTREPORTED", "STONY BROOK UNIVERSITY", "OFFICE OF THE CHIEF MEDICAL EXAMINER", 
"INSTITUTE OF LEGAL MEDICINE", "UNIVERSITY OF ALBERTA", "UNIVERSITY OF SAO PAULO", 
"CIUDAD UNIVERSITARIA S/N", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MALAWI", "MEDICAL NOBEL INSTITUTE", "ACADEMIC CENTRE FOR DENTISTRY AMSTERDAM (ACTA)", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "LABORATOIRE D'ANTHROPOLOGIE", "ADLI TIP ENSTITÜSÜ (INSTITUTE OF FORENSIC SCIENCES)", 
"MONASH UNIVERSITY", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", "CHARLES UNIVERSITY IN PRAGUE", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF THE WESTERN CAPE.", "HUMBOLDT UNIVERSITY OF BERLIN", 
"INSTITUTE OF LEGAL MEDICINE", "LAVAL UNIVERSITY", "SELCUK UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS AT ARLINGTON", "CHAR. - UNIVERSITATSMEDIZIN BERLIN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF FREIBURG", "HUMBOLDT UNIVERSITY OF BERLIN", "AKITA UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", 
"ROUEN UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITY CLINICS OF FREIBURG", 
"QUEEN MARY UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF THE WESTERN CAPE.", "HOKKAIDO UNIVERSITY", NA, 
"OSAKA UNIVERSITY", "LEEDS DENTAL INSTITUTE", "UNIVERSITY OF MACERATA", 
"HARVARD SCHOOL OF DENTAL MEDICINE", "UNIVERSITY OF GÖTEBORG", 
"NOTREPORTED", "SÜLEYMAN DEMIREL UNIVERSITY", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF OULU", "UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "UNIVERSITY OF LONDON", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, "TEL AVIV UNIVERSITY", "HOKKAIDO UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIV. OF NC AT CHAPEL HILL", "P.M.N.M. DENTAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", 
"BOURNEMOUTH UNIVERSITY", "FED. UNIVERSITY OF SÃO PAULO", "UNIVERSITY OF JAÉN", 
"KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "UNIVERSITY OF JAÉN", "HOKKAIDO UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF NIJMEGEN", "NEW YORK UNIVERSITY", "NOTREPORTED", 
"BAPUJI DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"SEOUL NATIONAL UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF ADELAIDE", "UNIVERSITY OF ŁÓDŹ", 
"GHENT UNIVERSITY", "HEBREW UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF SHEFFIELD", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ROCHESTER", "A.B SHETTY MEMORIAL INSTITUTE OF DENTAL SCIENCES", 
"LABORATOIRE DE MÉDECINE LÉGALE", "MADRID SCHOOL OF MINES", 
"WHITECHAPEL", "INSTITUT FÜR ANTHROPOLOGIE UND HUMANGENETIK", 
"UNIVERSITÉ DE MONTPELLIER II", "SCHOOL OF CLINICAL DENTISTRY", 
NA, "OSAKA UNIVERSITY", "DR. R. SCHULZE DEPARTMENT OF ORAL SURGERY", 
"UNIVERSITÀ DI PADOVA", "NOTREPORTED", "WEST TEXAS A AND M UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF BRITISH COLUMBIA", "VILNIUS UNIVERSITY", NA, "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF OTAGO", "NOTREPORTED", "SCHOOL OF DENTAL MEDICINE UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", 
"INSTITUT FÜR RECHTSMEDIZIN DER CAU ZU KIEL", "COOPERATIVE RESEARCH CENTRE FOR CONSERVATION AND MANAGEMENT OF MARSUPIALS", 
"UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", "NATIONAL PUBLIC HEALTH INSTITUTE", 
"NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI", "CORNELL UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SOUTH ALABAMA", "UNIVERSITY OF SASKATCHEWAN", 
NA, "THE HEBREW UNIVERSITY-HADASSAH SCHOOL OF DENTAL MEDICINE", 
NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", "OSAKA UNIV. FACULTY OF DENTISTRY", "CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN", 
NA, "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITÄT MÜNSTER", "UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", 
"NATIONAL SCIENCE MUSEUM", "NOTREPORTED", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF GRANADA", 
"WHITECHAPEL", "NIHON UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "EASTMAN DENTAL CENTER", 
"GÖTEBORG UNIVERSITY", "NOTREPORTED", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", 
"COLLEGE OF DENTAL SURGERY", "KING'S COLLEGE LONDON", "COLLEGE OF DENTAL SURGERY", 
"KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITY OF TENNESSEE", "MCMASTER UNIVERSITY", 
"NATIONAL SCIENCE MUSEUM", "UNIVERSITY OF GEORGIA", NA, "GENETIC IDENTIFICATION CENTER", 
NA, "SEA FISHERIES RESEARCH INSTITUTE", "UNIVERSITY OF LIEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF PENNSYLVANIA", "UNIVERSITY OF TORONTO", "FACULTY OF VETERINARY MEDICINE", 
"UNIVERSITÀ DI PADOVA", "UNIVERSITY OF WISCONSIN-MILWAUKEE", 
"TEXAS A AND M UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITÉ PARIS X-NANTERRE", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", 
"HUDDINGE UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL", NA, "FREE UNIVERSITY OF BERLIN", 
"FREIE UNIVERSITÄT BERLIN", "UNIVERSITY OF ZAGREB", NA, "CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND", "NOTREPORTED", "KAROLINSKA INSTITUTET", 
"KAROLINSKA INSTITUTET", "EMORY UNIVERSITY", "SAPPORO MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF GHENT", "SCHEUER", "SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "UNIVERSITY OF MELBOURNE", 
"MARINE MAMMAL CENTER", "UNIVERSITY OF BRADFORD", "UNIVERSITY OF WALES COLLEGE OF MEDICINE", 
"KAROLINSKA INSTITUTE", NA, "CHINA MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", "DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "GÖTEBORG UNIVERSITY", "CHINA MEDICAL UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF QUEENSLAND DENTAL SCHOOL", "UNIVERSITY OF BRISTOL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF BRISTOL", "UNIVERSITY OF BRISTOL", "KAROLINSKA INSTITUTET", 
"CASE WESTERN RESERVE UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", 
"KAROLINSKA INSTITUTET", "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "NOTREPORTED", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MALAYA", "UNIVERSITY OF TURKU", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
NA, "UNITED MEDICAL AND DENTAL SCHOOLS OF GUY'S AND ST. THOMAS'", 
"CENTRE FOR OVERSEAS RESEARCH AND DEVELOPMENT", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"WEINSTEIN", "KAROLINSKA INSTITUTET", "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", NA, 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF BRISTOL", "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "KAROLINSKA INSTITUTE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WALES", "UNIVERSITY OF MICHIGAN", "UNIVERSITY OF HONG KONG.", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WALES COLLEGE OF MEDICINE", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
NA, "CHRISTIAN-ALBRECHT-UNIVERSITÄT ZU KIEL", "MCMASTER UNIVERSITY", 
"TEMPLE UNIVERSITY SCHOOL OF DENTISTRY", "UNIVERSITY OF CALGARY", 
"NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF TURIN", "UNIVERSITY OF COPENHAGEN", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF PADOVA", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "PHILADELPHIA", 
"MCMASTER UNIVERSITY", NA, "DENTAL FACULTY", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", 
NA, NA, "FACULTY OF ODONTOLOGY", "KING EDWARD MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "UNIVERSITY OF BERGEN", "NOTREPORTED", 
"UNIVERSITY OF WALES COLLEGE OF MEDICINE", "SUN YAT-SEN UNIVERSITY OF MEDICAL SCIENCES", 
"NORWEGIAN POLAR RESEARCH INSTITUTE", "UNIVERSITY OF UMEÅ", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN", NA, "CENTRE OF DENTISTRY FOR THE HANDICAPPED", 
"SUN YAT-SEN UNIVERSITY OF MEDICAL SCIENCES", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MURCIA", "FACULTY OF ODONTOLOGY", "KUMAMOTO UNIVERSITY MEDICAL SCHOOL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF NEWCASTLE-UPON-TYNE", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF PADUA", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITY OF WALES", 
"MEDICAL COLLEGE OF GEORGIA.", "ROYAL EDINBURGH HOSPITAL", "KLINIKUM DER CHRISTIAN-ALBRECHTS-UNIVERSITÄT ZU KIEL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "ROYAL DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF EDINBURGH", "NOTREPORTED", "KANAGAWA DENTAL COLLEGE", 
NA, "CLEVELAND STATE UNIVERSITY", "KASTURBA MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"CORNELL UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF MURCIA", "CENTRAL FORENSIC SCIENCE LABORATORY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF OULU", "COLLEGE OF DENTISTRY", "NATIONAL RESEARCH INSTITUTE OF POLICE SCIENCE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "NOTREPORTED", "LINARES", "NOTREPORTED", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", "NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, "MEDICAL UNIVERSITY OF SOUTHERN AFRICA", 
"OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY", "PENNSYLVANIA STATE UNIVERSITY", "SCHOOL OF PATHOLOGY", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", "TOKYO WOMEN'S MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", "PANJAB UNIVERSITY", NA, "TEL-AVIV UNIVERSITY. TEL-AVIV", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ILLINOIS AT CHICAGO", "UNIVERSITY MUSEUM", "UNIVERSITY OF STELLENBOSCH", 
NA, NA, NA, "WASHINGTON UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSITY OF OXFORD", 
"UNIVERSITY OF MICHIGAN", "UNIVERSITY OF STELLENBOSCH", "NOTREPORTED", 
"NOTREPORTED", "NORTHWESTERN UNIVERSITY", "NORTHWESTERN UNIVERSITY", 
"UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", "UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", "WEST CHESTER UNIVERSITY", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF ALBERTA", "UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", "THE ROYAL DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY COLLEGE LONDON", NA, NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", 
"THE UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF THE WITWATERSRAND", 
"UNIVERSITY OF LUND", "UNIVERSITY OF VIRGINIA MEDICAL CENTER", 
"KENT STATE UNIVERSITY", NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", 
"NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", NA, NA, "BAYLOR COLLEGE OF DENTISTRY", 
"DUKE UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER", NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, 
"INSTITUTE OF CHILD HEALTH", "NOTREPORTED", NA, "NOTREPORTED", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, "THE MIDDLESEX HOSPITAL MEDICAL SCHOOL", NA, 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, "STOMATOLOGICAL FACULTY BELGRADE", "FORTRESS", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF OSLO", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF THE WITWATERSRAND", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ROYAL DENTAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF TORONTO", "UNIVERSITY OF TENNESSEE", "UNIVERSITY OF MICHIGAN", 
"NOTREPORTED", "UNIV. HELSINKI", NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, NA, 
"UNIVERSITY OF CALGARY", "UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", "UNIVERSITY OF PENNSYLVANIA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", NA, NA, "DEPARTMENT OF ARCHAEOLOGY UNIVERSITY OF CAPE TOWN", 
"UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", NA, "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", "SCHOOL OF DENTAL SURGERY", NA, NA, 
NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, "CASE WESTERN RESERVE UNIVERSITY", NA, 
NA, NA, "UNIV. LEEDS", NA, "UNIVERSITÉ DE MONTRÉAL", "CENTRAL FORENSIC SCIENCE LABORATORY", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF MANITOBA", NA, "NOTREPORTED", "HARVARD SCH. PUBL. HLTH", 
"FED. UNIV. SANTA MARIA", NA, "KAROLINSKA INSTITUTE", "COLLEGE OF MEDICINE OF THE UNIVERSITY OF LAGOS", 
"UNIVERSITY OF STOCKHOLM", NA, "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, "UNIV. QUEENSLAND", NA, "UNIV. LUND", NA, 
NA, "LONDON HOSPITAL MEDICAL COLLEGE", "UNIVERSITY OF GLASGOW DENTAL SCHOOL", 
"MEDICAL COLLEGE", "NOTREPORTED", "AUSTRALIAN DEPARTMENT OF HEALTH", 
"UNIV. HELSINKI", "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", "UNIV. MONTREAL", 
"UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA", NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, "SOUTHWEST FOUNDATION FOR RESEARCH AND EDUCATION", 
"UNIVERSITY OF KENTUCKY", "UNIVERSITY OF MISSOURI", "NOTREPORTED", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, "THE LONDON HOSPITAL MEDICAL COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF BERGEN", "INSTITUTE OF DENTAL SURGERY", "NOTREPORTED", 
"WELSH NATIONAL SCHOOL OF MEDICINE", "CENTRAL WASHINGTON STATE COLLEGE", 
"NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", NA, "UNIVERSITY OF WISCONSIN-MILWAUKEE", 
"NOTREPORTED", "COLLINS", NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, "DEPARTMENT OF AGRICULTURE", 
"NOTREPORTED", NA, "REGIONAL HEALTH OFFICE", "UNIVERSITY OF HELSINKI", 
"RESEARCH UNIT", "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF BERGEN", NA, "DALHOUSIE UNIVERSITY", 
"EQUINE RESEARCH STATION", "NOTREPORTED", "ROYAL COLLEGE OF SURGEONS OF ENGLAND", 
"NOTREPORTED", "DENTAL COLLEGE AND HOSPITAL", NA, "REGIONAL HEALTH OFFICE", 
NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, NA, NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", 
NA, "UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA", NA, NA, NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", "NATIONAL MUSEUM CENTRE FOR PREHISTORY AND PALAEONTOLOGY", 
NA, "FELS RESEARCH INSTITUTE FOR THE STUDY OF HUMAN DEVELOPMENT", 
NA, "RAUSCH", "NOTREPORTED", "NOTREPORTED", "FELS RESEARCH INSTITUTE FOR THE STUDY OF HUMAN DEVELOPMENT", 
NA, NA, "ARIZONA STATE UNIVERSITY", "OREGON REGIONAL PRIMATE RESEARCH CENTER", 
"NOTREPORTED", "THE UNIVERSITY OF MICHIGAN", NA, NA, NA, "NOTREPORTED", 
NA, "NOTREPORTED", NA, "NOTREPORTED", "UNIVERSITY OF DELHI", 
"FORSYTH DENTAL CENTER")
```

What I wanted to do is to find an approximate match between the strings, so I can edit it. If it is possible, I want to have an output somewhat like this:

```
[1] "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN", 
"CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY LEUVEN", "KU LEUVEN - UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN".
[2] "UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA", "THE UNIVERSITY OF WESTERN AUSTRALIA".
[3] ....
```

and so on.

Is there something that can make my job cleaning the names easier?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agrep`:

```r
unique(x[agrep("UNIVERSITY LEUVEN", x, max.distance = 3)])
[1] "KU LEUVEN - UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN" "KATHOLIEKE UNIVERSITEIT LEUVEN"  
[3] "CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY LEUVEN"       "CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN"   
[5] "UNIVERSITY OF LEUVEN"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ‘levenshteinSim’ from RecordLinkage package.

This returns a similarity between two strings used as

```
Similarity <- 100 * levenshteinSim(String1, String2)
```

Give it a try!